# Stuck on splash screen on first launch but if we don't kill app and launch app again the app works fine. (react-native) Android

Tags: android, react-native, react-native-navigation, wix-react-native-navigation

I have upgraded code to react-native 0.59.9 from 0.53.3. I think I may have missed some essential steps and getting launch issues. Please check and help me to make app work fine.

React Native Navigation version: 4.0.6

React Native version: 0.59.9

Platform(s) (iOS, Android, or both?): Android.

Device info: Device and Simulator Both (All Android versions).

---

### MainActivity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends NavigationActivity {
static Backbonebits b;
public void addDefaultSplashLayout() {
LinearLayout splash = new LinearLayout(this);
Drawable splash_screen_bitmap = ContextCompat.getDrawable(getApplicationContext(),R.drawable.splashscreen);
splash.setBackground(splash_screen_bitmap);

    setContentView(splash);
}
@override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
MobileAds.initialize(this, new OnInitializationCompleteListener() {
@override
public void onInitializationComplete(InitializationStatus initializationStatus) {
}
});
b = new Backbonebits(this);
}
}
```

---

### MainApplication.java

```
public class MainApplication extends NavigationApplication {

private static CallbackManager mCallbackManager = CallbackManager.Factory.create();

protected static CallbackManager getCallbackManager() {
    return mCallbackManager;
}

 @Override
 protected ReactGateway createReactGateway() {
     ReactNativeHost host = new NavigationReactNativeHost(this, isDebug(), createAdditionalReactPackages()) {
         @Override
         protected String getJSMainModuleName() {
             return "index";
         }
     };
     return new ReactGateway(this, isDebug(), host);
 }

 @Override
 public boolean isDebug() {
     return BuildConfig.DEBUG;
 }

protected List<ReactPackage> getPackages() {
  return Arrays.<ReactPackage>asList(
        new MainReactPackage(),
        new FBSDKPackage(mCallbackManager),
  );
}

 @Override
 public List<ReactPackage> createAdditionalReactPackages() {
     return getPackages();
 }
}
```

---

### App.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {
Platform
} from 'react-native';
import { Navigation } from 'react-native-navigation'
import TermsOfUseController from "./app/routes/TermsOfUseController"
import Utility from './app/config/Utility';

const registerScreen = (name, component, styles) => {
component.navigatorStyle = {
...defaultNavigatorStyles,
...styles
};
Navigation.registerComponent(name, () => component)
}

function registerAllScreens() {
registerScreen('MyApp.LoginController', LoginController, {})
}

registerAllScreens();

User.loggedInUser((user) => {
User.addSignOutListner()
var screenName = 'MyApp.LoginController';
if (user) {
if (user.id != 0 && user.id != undefined) {
Utility.isFirstTimeLaunch = true
screenName = 'MyApp.HomeScreenController'; // User Already logged in
}
else {
Utility.isFirstTimeLaunch = true
screenName = 'MyApp.LoginController'; // Not Logged in
}
}
});

Navigation.events().registerAppLaunchedListener(() => {

Navigation.setRoot({
  root: {
    stack: {
      children: [{
        component: {
          name: screenName,
          passProps: { ...Navigation }
        }
      }],
      options: {
        topBar: {
          visible: false
        },
      }
    }
  }
});
});
});
```

Answer (score 2):

I had launch listeners inside user check condition. I resolved it by keeping it outside. It created problem in android, It was working on iOS though.